# Sort user's posts based on content length

Tags: support, search, content

I am looking for a way to sort the list of my answers on a Stack Exchange site by the size of content (number of words). I am looking to hand pick article length answers that I have written in past.

The only sorting criterion that I can find is based on date of posting, votes and activity.

Is there a way to do so? I am not really interested in the count of words, just the sorted output with lengthiest to shortest answers.

It would also be nice to know if a post contains image(s) and URL(s).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no sort option for content length on the website, so we'll have to resort to other methods like the [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com). [This query](https://data.stackexchange.com/apple/query/1076883/posts-by-a-single-user-sorted-by-content-length?UserId=279727) lists your lengthiest answers on Ask Different, including the number of links and images:

[image: SEDE query results]

Note that clickable images (`[![][1]][1]`) will count twice; once for the image and once for the link.

Since SEDE is updated once a week, on Sunday morning, new answers won't appear immediately. Feel free to [fork](https://data.stackexchange.com/apple/query/fork/1076883) the query to adapt it to your needs. If you want to experiment, do try the awesome [tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial).